# How to get unmatched columns members in two sheets and copy them to a new sheet in excel?

Tags: excel

1. I have two sheets in workbook. Sheet1 and sheet2.
2. Sheet1 has colA, Sheet2 has colA and colB.
3. colA in sheet2 is a subset of colA in sheet1.
4. Required to match colA in both the sheets and
5. should get unmatched coloumn members i.e members which are present in   sheet1 but not present in sheet 2 in a new sheet i.e sheet3.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

In Sheet1 B1 copied down to suit:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,A1)
```

Filter that column to select `0`, select and copy what's visible in ColumnA and paste into Sheet3.